# cURL gets 401.2 error with https

Tags: php, curl, https, iis-6, ntlm

I tried everything I found here but nothing really helped.
I am trying to connect to a IIS6.0 *.svc-file through HTTPS. This is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curl_options = array(
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 6,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
);

if(isset($options['login'])){
    $options[CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH] = CURLAUTH_NTLM;
    $options[CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH] = true;
    $options[CURLOPT_USERPWD] = $login;
}

if(isset($options['params'])){
    array_walk($options['params'], 'curl_escape', $ch);
    $curl_options[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
    $curl_options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $options['params'];
}

curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The only thing I get is a 401.2 error, saying, the server doesn't like my authentication method.
I also tried `$options[CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH] = CURLAUTH_ANY;` but that didn't work either.

The credentials are formatted correctly with `user:pw` and are 100% correct.
The thing is: accessing the page with a browser is no problem and gives me the correct xml-output.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try these for https:

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
2. While using CURLOPT_USERPWD, make sure your $login has the value as username:password format.
3. Use CURLAUTH_BASIC instead of CURLAUTH_NTLM

Comment: the $login has the correct format and NTLM needs to be set because I know that it's the method, the server uses
I'm gonna try the first one tomorrow, though

Comment: Ok, tried everything, nothing worked :-/ But thanks anyway :)

Anyone else?